# Submit Button in While Loop

Tags: php, forms, while-loop

I have products that are printed to a screen in a while loop form and 'add_to_cart' buttons that go along with them.

I want to be able to press the "add to cart" button and add the selected product above it to the "$selectedProduct" variable. But when I press it nothing happens to it and the variable stays blank.

```
  <?php 

  include('connect.php'); 
  require("session.php"); 


        //create the sql statement 
        $sql_all=
             "SELECT * FROM product 
              ORDER BY product_ID DESC";
        $result_all = mysqli_query($con,$sql_all);


        //PRINT OUT ALL THE PRODUCT
        while ($row_all = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_all)) 
                {
                    echo '<form method="post">';
                        echo '<u>'.$row_all["name"].'</u>';

                        echo '<br>';

                        echo '<button name="add_to_cart" type="submit">Add to Cart</button>';

                        echo '<hr>';
                    echo '</form>';



                }



            if(isset($_POST["add_to_cart"]))
            {

                //CREATE A VARIABLE THAT HOLDS THE SELECTED PRODUCTED TO BE ADDED TO CART
                    $selectedProduct = $row_all["name"];

                echo 'Selected Product  = '.$selectedProduct;

            }

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Neither your form has an action, nor you have a javascript to handle the form submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you seem to have not added anything to go through the post method. Find the below code i have shown you how to do it the right way. This will add that selected product to that specific variable each time.

```
while ($row_all = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_all)) 
                {
                    echo '<form method="post">';
                        echo '<u>'.$row_all["name"].'</u>';

                        echo '<br>';

                        echo '<button name="add_to_cart" value='.$row_all['name'].' type="submit">Add to Cart</button>';

                        echo '<hr>';
                    echo '</form>';



                }



            if(isset($_POST["add_to_cart"]))
            {

                //CREATE A VARIABLE THAT HOLDS THE SELECTED PRODUCTED TO BE ADDED TO CART
                    $selectedProduct = $_POST["add_to_cart"];

                echo 'Selected Product  = '.$selectedProduct;

            }

    mysqli_close($conn);
```

However if u want it to add or iterate the amount of products each time so that the variable stores many products. You will have to use a session variable

Comment: I added your code but when I select an item that has more than one word, it only selects the first word. Any ideas?

Comment: Use mysqli_fetch_array instead of associative array >>>

 while ($row_all = mysqli_fetch_array($result_all))

Comment: Same thing, only echoing the first word

Comment: Fixed it. Replaced the value in the form with a variable to hold it and put it around double quotes.  

                            echo '<button name="add_to_cart" value="'.$p.'" type="submit">Add to Cart</button>';

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php 

  include('connect.php'); 
  require("session.php"); 


        //create the sql statement 
        $sql_all=
             "SELECT * FROM product 
              ORDER BY product_ID DESC";
        $result_all = mysqli_query($con,$sql_all);
while ($row_all = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_all)) 
                {
                    echo '<form method="post">';
                        echo '<u>'.$row_all["name"].'</u>';

                        echo '<br>';

                        echo '<button name="add_to_cart" value='.$row_all['name'].' type="submit">Add to Cart</button>';

                        echo '<hr>';
                    echo '</form>';



                }



            if(isset($_POST["add_to_cart"]))
            {

                //CREATE A VARIABLE THAT HOLDS THE SELECTED PRODUCTED TO BE ADDED TO CART
                    $selectedProduct = $_POST["add_to_cart"];

                echo 'Selected Product  = '.$selectedProduct;

            }

        mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```